# Ajax Status is 200 but responseText is parseError

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to validate my code that shows an error message if the search form is empty or no results found however, it doesn't work. Based on the AJAX response its a 200 but parse error.

Here's my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({
            url : ajax_url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data : data,
            beforeSend : function ( e ) {
                 e.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
            },
            success : function(response) {
                mafs.find("ul").empty();
                //if(response) {
                if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response)){
                    for(var i = 0 ;  i < response.length ; i++) {
                        var html  = "<li id='movie-" + response[i].id + "'>";
                        html += "  <a href='" + response[i].permalink + "' title='" + response[i].title + "'>";
                        html += "      <img src='" + response[i].poster + "' alt='" + response[i].title + "' />";
                        html += "      <div class='movie-info'>";
                        html += "          <h4>" + response[i].title + "</h4>";
                        html += "          <p>" + response[i].content + "</p>";
                        html += "      </div>";
                        html += "  </a>";
                        html += "</li>";
                        mafs.find("ul").append(html);
                    }
                } else {
                    var html  = "<p class='no-result'>No matching movies found. Try a different filter or search keyword</[li]>";
                    mafs.find("ul").append(html);
                }
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }    
        });
```

And here's my PHP code too

```
function my_ajax_filter_search_callback() {
 
    header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
 
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
 
   if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $search = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['search'] );
        $search_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            /*'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'tax_query' => $tax_query,*/
            's' => $search
        ) );
    } else {
        $search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
 
    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        $result = array();
 
        while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
            $search_query->the_post();
 
            $cats = strip_tags( get_the_category_list(", ") );
            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "content" => get_the_content(),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
                "poster" => wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full')
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();
 
        echo json_encode($result);
 
    } else {
        echo 'no posts found';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

So I'm not sure what's the issue here, tried dataType: 'json' but it still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the _exact_ error message you're seeing, and where?

Comment: Also, why are you using `contentType: "application/json"` and `e.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')`? Those settings are for telling the server that you're _sending_ JSON in the request, not that you're expecting to receive it back. Are you actually sending JSON in the request? Because the way the PHP code is written, it does not seem to be expecting to receive any JSON.

Comment: @ADyson: statusText: "parsererror" is the error and it doesn't run the success function conditional 'else'

Comment: @ADyson I tried removing those you have mentioned but still same error. My apologies

Comment: I didn't say they were the cause of the error, they are additional problems.

Comment: `statusText: "parsererror"`...you see that in your console?? Can you provide a screenshot? If jQuery failed to parse the response as JSON you'd get a different error. Also have you inspected the raw response coming back from the PHP (using your browser's Network tool) to check if it contains pure JSON or not? If there's any additional content (such as HTML) or if the response is not parseable as JSON in any way, that could cause a problem, but the error message you're reporting is unusual.

Comment: @ADyson: Here's the screenshot of the error: http://prntscr.com/218n8r2

Comment: Ah, well, if you look at responseText, you'll see it's just plain text, not JSON. Make sure the PHP always returns actual JSON. That could be the cause.

Comment: it literally said in ur function code, `no post found`. somehow, your function doesnt return any value

Comment: @ADyson, I see so how do I get it to work in order for it to run on the success function conditional that I currently have?

Comment: Ok, I got it sorted out. I just echoed out the  echo json_encode($result); on my else statement in PHP. 

Thank you so much for the help. It does indeed help when there an extra pair of eyes

Answer (score 1):

Return message in JSON when no post found. Try to return something like this.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'message' => 'no posts found'
));
```